# Selenium Webdriver: How to take full page screenshot using FireShot written in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium Webdriver, I am looking to be able to take a full page screenshot using FireShot executed from a Python script.

I have the following code so far:

```
import unittest
import execjs
from execjs import get
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearc(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver');

    def test_login_and_make_payment_on_account(self):
        driver = self.driver;
        driver.set_window_size(1024,768);

        # Log in to My Account
        driver.get("https://www.mywebsite.com");
        self.assertIn("Sign In", driver.title);
        driver.save_screenshot('/Users/username/Documents/Selenium_Test/01a_login.png');

        # Enter username
        user = driver.find_element_by_id("EmailOrAccountNumber");
        user.send_keys("user@me.co.uk");

        # Enter password and submit form
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("Password");
        password.send_keys("password123");
        driver.save_screenshot('/Users/username/Documents/Selenium_Test/01b_login_filled.png');
        password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN);

        # Confirm logged into My Account
        self.assertIn("Account Summary", driver.title);
        driver.save_screenshot('/Users/username/Documents/Selenium_Test/02a_My_Account.png');

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close();

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main();
```

I have installed PyExecJS, but have no idea how I can begin using the FireShot API to replace the current save_screenshot functions used in the code. Thank you for any steer or guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use [driver.execute_script](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=execute_script#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) command to execute your javascript in the browser, but if you want to check a markup, perhaps, [applitools](https://applitools.com) could help you

Comment: Can you expand on why you think driver.execute_script command is better and how it would be written with the code presented? Looks like I can do: `driver.execute_script("http://screenshot-program.com/dloads/fsapi.js", args)` but what should the args be to save a full page screenshot to disk?

Comment: You can do something like this (fix the indentation):

`with open('fsapi.js') as f:`
`fireshot_api = f.read()`
`driver.execute_script('{0}; FireShotAPI.savePage(true);'.format(fireshot_api))`

Comment: I'm looking for a similar answer to OP. I need to use an ext. because printing as PDF causes the page to be reformatted for printer-friendly formatting (such as multi-page). I just want a PDF of the whole page as seen. A long PDF if the page is scroll-able.  I'm using the `fireshot-1.11.25.xpi` file and adding the extension to the Firefox web driver. Any idea what script I can execute to cause the desired effect?